# Clipboard.GetImage() returning null

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard

I have a `DataGridView` that contains an `Image` Column and some Text Columns.  I have a pretty simple handler that will allow the user to Copy Text or Images out of the cells and Paste Images and Text into them.  The Copy/Paste works fine on Text, but the Paste does not work on the Images.  (NOTE: If I Paste an image that was placed on the clipboard from another app, like Paint, then it works fine)

If I immediately call a `Clipboard.GetImage()` after the `Clipboard.SetImage()` it works fine, which leads me to believe that it could be a scope problem or that `Clipboard` is grabbing a reference and not the underlying bytes from the image.  Do I have to place the raw image bytes in a shared location?  I checked the [MSDN definition for GetImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getimage(v=vs.110).aspx) to make sure I was doing it correctly.

```
    private void dataGridView_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
        {
            if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
            {
                Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();  // always returns null

                if (cell.ColumnIndex == _imageCol)
                    cell.Value = img;
            }

            if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
            {
                if (cell.ColumnIndex != _imageCol)
                    cell.Value = Clipboard.GetText(); // always works
            }
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0];

            if (cell.ColumnIndex == _imageCol)
            {
                Clipboard.SetImage((Image)cell.Value);
                Image img2 = Clipboard.GetImage();  // successfully returns the Image
            }
            else
                Clipboard.SetText((string)cell.Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can confirm this. Atm it looks as if caching the image in a variable is a simple workaround.. But I'd like to know if anything should be done to make the clipboard content persist..

Comment: Did you see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/154503/clipboard-content-automatically-erased)?

Comment: @TaW:  I had not found that one yet.  I'm checking into it to see if I can monitor the Clipboard.  Its just odd that it does not affect Text on the clipboard.

Comment: True. Somewhere at the back of my mind, there is a hunch that binary data may be treated special because they tend to be so large..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are not counting on is that DataGridView *also* implements copy/paste.  Using the same shortcut keystrokes as you are using, Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V.  So it looks like it works just after you put the image on the clipboard, but then DGV does it as well and overwrites the clipboard content.  Unfortunately it doesn't copy images, just text.  An empty string for your image column.

You have to tell it that you handled the keystroke:

```
    private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control) {
            // etc...
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control) {
            // etc...
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Headslap! Yes, this is the correct answer. (As usual..)

Comment: You got it!  How stupid of me to forget to set Handled to true when I've done it a million times.  Thanks Hans!